# Cross product YES-NO answer model

Tags: psychology

I was just thinking, many questionnaires model yes/no answers as one or the other, with some logicians using fuzzy logic to describe situations in between.

I wonder though, if yes and no were regarded as different emotions rather than as just answers, couldn't one just give a percentage for each, for example when filling out a questionnaire?

Has this approach been used?

[image: square with yes no sides with circle within square indicating answer]

CF: Think of Katy Perry's song, "you're hot and you're cold, you're yes and you're no..." :-)

Comment: Without any hard facts: I find the idea compelling; you could derive how conflicted the decision is (implying maybe how likely to change) and how important. Hoewever, I'd imagine respondents will have problems dealing with it, as it goes against the notion of "yes or no".

Comment: Good one. I suppose that's two more reasons to think about it. Thanks.

Comment: But then if the question wss repeated, and there was even more correlations or discorrelations between the overlapping parts, maybe you could deduce even more... or, who knows, even less. :-p:-) :-D :-D :/ :-D

Comment: Just stubled over this: http://www.latimes.com/politics/la-na-pol-poll-faq-20161006-snap-story.html which uses "How likely are you to..."  for two options that are exclusive. It's slightly different form YES/NO, as there is the option of "neither" - but I think asking "how likely are you..."  would solve the problem I see with the "yes/no" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawing you've showed us is typically used to put you (or something) in a category when two major independent features are being analyzed. Let me give as example the [Political Compass](https://www.politicalcompass.org/):

[image: political compass]

Other possibility is the [Myers Briggs Type Indicator](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers_Briggs_Type_Indicator) (to which you can find [tests online](http://www.keirsey.com/4temps/overview_temperaments.asp)) with four major features being analysed:

[image: Meyer Briggs Indicator diagram]

Both examples are a final product and typically not a user input widget. You give yes/no (more/less) answers to a few questions and the engine will place somewhere in the diagram.

If the idea is to directly get user input than most providers I've seen [use 1D sliders or choices](http://mashable.com/2011/03/06/user-feedback-apps/#fVgFbvGYGkqx) for each major feature they want to question. For example the political compass could be:

```
Economic Left <------------X------------------------------------> Economic Right


Libertarian <--X------------------------------------------------> Authoritarian
```

But an actual widget [could be](https://www.questionpro.com/blog/updated-4-scales-every-researcher-should-remember/), for three major features:

[image: Satisfaction sliders]

Its usually easier for people to answer yes/no questions for small stuff than seeing the bigger picture and locate themselves in a global picture. For example, I've seen people very surprised with the result they've obtained in both political compass and Meyer Briggs Type Indicator. Should they point directly where they would have stayed in the diagram and they would have given a wrong answer.

This does not mean, however, that this widget as input would never work. As you mentioned if instead of political categories you would have emotions it would seem, to me, a good tool to quickly place your result (since its an intuitive knowledge about yourself).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about [Net Promoter Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_Promoter)

Here's a [sample NPS form](https://www.surveymonkey.co.uk/mp/net-promoter-score-survey-template/)

There are so [many ways to measure user engagement and system usability](https://www.measuringu.com/blog/measure-manage-ux.php) and not all of them use the yes/no paradigm

If you're interested in learning more about measuring user experiences and UX research in general then I'd recommend [Measuring The User Experience](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0124157815) by Bill Albert and Tom Tullis